# Download AWK to Ubuntu

Tags: bash, awk

How to download `awk` to Ubuntu, since I tried to use `asorti` function and it told me that there is an error on this `asorti`. I tried many scripts that used `asorti` function and the same error occure!

Comment: Why do you think you need to "downlowd" awk? Please edit your question adding the exact error you are getting when trying to use the asorti function and the output of `awk --version`

Comment: @steeldriver the output of awk --version is :
 ` awk: not an option: --version `

Comment: Well, that at least shows that `awk` is installed. To see what version of `awk` you have, run `awk -W version`. Based on the fact that it _is_ installed, you might want to edit your question or create a new one.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like your system is using `mawk` to provide awk - you can check with

```
update-alternatives --display awk
```

If that is the case, you should be able to install GNU awk (`gawk`) from the repository either using the Software Center or other GUI package manager, or via the command line using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

This should automatically set your default awk to `gawk` using the update-alternatives mechanism - if you need to set it back to `mawk` you can do so by running

```
sudo update-alternatives --config awk
```

and following the on-screen instructions. The *asorti* function is a GNU awk extension.

Comment: i have run my script using the following : `./project t ` , but it's give me the following error : 
`
./project: line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./project: line 43: `    num = asorti(myArray)'
`

Comment: @user2162652 And now what is the output of `update-alternatives --display awk`?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu , the above answer solved partially the problem , but it's still give me a syntax error , on code that has no error , as i said in last comment

Comment: @user2162652 How can you be sure that the code has no error since it has? And now,  what is the output of `update-alternatives --display awk`?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu the output is :
awk - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/gawk
/usr/bin/gawk - priority 10
  slave awk.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gawk.1.gz
  slave nawk: /usr/bin/gawk
  slave nawk.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gawk.1.gz
/usr/bin/mawk - priority 5
  slave awk.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/mawk.1.gz
  slave nawk: /usr/bin/mawk
  slave nawk.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/mawk.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/gawk'.

Comment: Does your script have a 'shebang' at the top, like `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` or `#!/usr/bin/env awk -f`? if so what is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also download the gawk source code files from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk and then proceed to compile them. This approach may be useful if you want to use a specific version of gawk other than the one provided by the `gawk` package in Ubuntu's repositories.

After downloading the source code, extract the files in a given directory `/home/user/gawk/` and then:

```
cd /home/user/gawk
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Most probably it will be installed in something like `/usr/local/bin/gawk-4.X.Y`, being X and Y numbers that change on every new release.

Comment: @EliahKagan well it may be useful if you want to use a specific version. OK, good to have this insight, I was not aware of it. Updated, thanks! For the future, I think it is even more effective to [edit] the post to make it better rather than just downvoting. After all, this is cc content that gets improved by everyone's efforts ;-)

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "just downvoting"--I commented with my two criticisms, and unnecessary `sudo` use was the *less* serious one. (Building from source can be useful, but it would be unfortunate if readers start building stuff from source only because they think they must do so. Building from source unnecessarily and learning bad habits for it is the worst of all.) *But I see how my comment could've been unclear.* Now that you've said *why* you suggest this, I *have* edited to include that. Though I don't agree this is likely to help the OP, the post is improved and I've undownvoted.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes, my point was about providing this useful insight and downvoting for its inaccuracies instead of changing it, as you courteously did now. My _just downvoting_ expression was not polite, sorry for that. Related to the answer itself, I posted it a while ago when I discovered a new version of GNU Awk was released and decided to test it locally without interfering the one that runs in my server currently. This was the only way I found to do it.